# Asus Xonar DSX causing freezes

Tags: windows-8, freeze, crash, sound-card

I have an Asus Xonar DSX sound card installed in my system that has been giving me grief lately, and Asus support and Google searches have been no help in figuring out what's wrong with it. The drivers I'm running are the most recent Uni Xonar drivers.

The card causes my system to become completely unresponsive (frozen) when driving any audio through the card. This can be something as simple as watching something on youtube, or playing a resource intensive game. The problem does not occur when the card is installed, but unused, i.e: when I use my GPU as a sound card through HDMI-out, or when using my onboard audio.

So I've narrowed it down to either being a hardware or software issue with the card, but I cannot determine which it is. I'll just be sending the card back if it turns out to be a hardware issue, so my question today, is how to I rule out a software problem? I have WinDBG on the machine, but I don't know how helpful it will be, as the system doesn't come up with any error messages, it just freezes completely. The only way to regain control of the system is to power it off and restart it.

Here are the specs on the system:
AMD Athlon II X4 645
AMD Radeon HD 6670
8GB DDR3
the aforementioned Xonar DSX
7200rpm HDD
220w PSU (I thought it could be the psu causing the problem; same problem happens when running a 450w unit)
Windows 8 Pro w/ Media Center

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problems with this sound card (PC grinds to a halt and then BSODs) but fortunately the fix was simple: **turn off GX** (the little button in bottom right corner of the Xonar DSX Audio Center utility).

The specs for the affected PC are:
Windows 7 64Bit Professional (SP1)
Intel Core i5-2400 @3.10GHz
4GB RAM
Dell Mainboard (Dell Vostro 260s)

Edit: The Uni drivers are affected by this bug too.